# Search in personal inbox

Tags: support, search, global-inbox

I intend to find an important notification in my inbox.

There's over one hundred pages amongst which most are insignificant and of similarity. It's difficult to pick desired one.

Is it possible to search inside inbox by keywords?

Comment: The accepted answer works, but it's barely an improvement over manually scrolling through 90 pages of messages, which is impractical. ¶ Surely there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox#page=1&pagesize=100&filter=!*L6Kz8BmNX1ky9u_&run=true)

I have 5140 inbox messages. At 100 messages per page that is 52 requests. Those items collected into an array can then be searched using whatever search method you see fit... and can write.

Have fun!

---

<sup>I was going to write a stack snippet that demonstrated usage, but Stack Snippets do not allow popups, as such authentication can not be achieved, and the inbox can not be accessed. It's fairly simple though, plenty of docs to work with</sup>